# App for inserting images in PDF file

Tags: android, pdf

Currently iam using Adobe PDF app, and I want to insert image in that file. But there is no option for *adding image*. Is there any other app for PDF in which I can add images?

Comment: One thing: PDF editors are rare even on PC, and often are paid apps.

Comment: As Andy wrote: what is your price margin – in case such an app exists but is paid? Not a big chance, though: I've not encountered any PDF editor for Android yet. But be welcome to browse [my list of PDF apps](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_pdf), maybe I missed that feature on one of them.

Answer (score 2):

Xodo app allows to add image in PDF file.
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]